# Magento - Shipping & VAT for Zero Rated & 20% Products

Tags: shipping, vat

I am getting a little lost in the complexity of TAX settings and shipping.

Issue: I sell both 0% and 20% VAT applicable products.  When I sell a 0% product, then shipping is to be set at 0% VAT.  When I sell a 20% product shipping is to be set at 20% VAT.  When I have a mix of 0% & 20%, shipping should be set to 20%.

This is what I have tried to date:

Set shipping Tax Rate:

```
Config > Sales > Tax > Tax Class for Shipping > SHIPPING
```

On its own this does not apply/show any VAT at checkout for shipping.

Sales > Tax > Tax Rules - - I have added SHIPPING to both Zero Rated and 20% VAT rules
RESULT:  This adds VAT to shipping when only a 0% product is in basket

`Sales > Tax > Tax Rules` 
 I have added SHIPPING to 20% VAT rule only
RESULT:  This adds VAT to shipping when only a 0% product is in basket

`Sales > Tax > Tax Rules` 
 I have added SHIPPING to Zero Rated VAT rule only
RESULT:  This does not add VAT to shipping when 20% product is in basket.

Can someone help me out with a solution.  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From everyone I have spoken to, magento cannot handle UK Tax rules 100%.  I subsequently found a module built specifically for this.  Was up and running within 30 mins!

https://www.c3media.co.uk/c3-uk-shipping-tax.html